# Hostname cannot be resolved to IP address

Tags: dns, cpanel, hosts, whm

I have recently started running a VPS through godaddy and I continue to receive the following automatically generate email from cPanel:

```
Your hostname (server.mydomain.com) could not be resolved to an IP
address. This means that /etc/hosts is not set up correctly, and/or
there is no dns entry for server.mydomain.com. Please be sure that
the contents of /etc/hosts are configured correctly, and also that
there is a correct 'A' entry for the domain in the zone file.

Some or all of these problems can be caused by /etc/resolv.conf
being setup incorrectly. Please check that file if you believe
everything else is correct.

You may be able to automatically correct this problem by using the
'Add an A entry for your hostname' option under 'Dns Functions' in
your Web Host Manager.
```

I have followed the advice in the email and added an A entry, but still receive the error.

When I attempt to add a dns zone to server.mydomain.com, WHM tells me `Sorry, a DNS entry for server.mydomain.com already exists.`

However, there is no DNS zone listed in WHM for me to view or edit for my hostname.

I am able to connect to the server through server.mydomain.com, so it seems to me that the host name is actually resolving correctly. Also, the IP and alias are listed correctly in `/etc/hosts`.

Why am I receiving this email and how can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, this error email is generated by private name servers not being set up correctly.  Also there is chance for missing, corrupted or improperly formatted DNS records.

If you are using private name servers , then please check the following:

1. Did you register your private name servers with your registrar with the correct IP addresses?
2. Is there an A record for each of your private name servers?
3. Are the correct nameservers listed in the DNS Zone for the domain using them?